# Proving $\sin(x)\cos(2kx) = [\sin((2k+1)x)-\sin((2k-1)x)]/2$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, fourier-series

I am trying to calculate the following integral related to fourier series
$$4/\pi\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin(x)\cos(2kx) \, dx .$$

I plugged it into an online integral calculator and wanted to see the step by step solution. The first step was using the equation
$$\sin(x)\cos(2kx) = \frac{\sin((2k+1)x)-\sin((2k-1)x)}2.$$
Why does it hold?

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**. From
$$
\sin(a+b)=\sin a \cos b+\sin b \cos a
$$$$
\sin(a-b)=\sin a \cos b-\sin b \cos a
$$ one gets
$$
2\sin a\cos b=\sin(a+b)+\sin(a-b).
$$

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to try:$$e^{x+iy}=e^x(cosy+isiny)\\e^{y+ix}=e^y(cosx+isinx)\\e^{(x+y)+i(x+y)}=e^{x+y}{[cos(x+y)+isin(x+y)]}$$